# How to unhide page item in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image]Does any one knows how to unhide page item on oracle apex?

[image: apex_issue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change its type. Currently, it is "Hidden" - set it to (for example) "Text field".

Comment: Robertas - this should be a little over to the right of your screenshot, in the item properties.